# Deploying Django To Heroku - Server Error (500)

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have been making a django app, and am now trying to deploy it to heroku.
However when I go on it, says `Server Error (500)`, and the log says: `2017-05-27T21:00:14.634310+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=remberit.herokuapp.com request_id=065d27c6-9211-458f-9fc6-bb677d43581e fwd="86.13.204.65" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=151ms status=500 bytes=387 protocol=https`

Here is my settings.py (at learst the relevant parts, but please ask if you would like the rest):

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "staticfiles")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'

import dj_database_url

DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

DEBUG = False

try:
    from .local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

And here is my wsgi.py:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
#from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
import django

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'remberit.settings')
django.setup()

application = get_wsgi_application()
#application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

Here is my Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn remberit.wsgi
```

Here is my runtime.txt:

```
python-3.5.2
```

Here is my requirements.txt:

```
appdirs==1.4.3
dj-database-url==0.4.2
gunicorn==19.7.1
packaging==16.8
pyparsing==2.2.0
six==1.10.0
whitenoise==3.3.0
psycopg2==2.6.2
```

And here is the output of `pip freeze`:

```
appdirs==1.4.3
dj-database-url==0.4.2
gunicorn==19.7.1
packaging==16.8
pyparsing==2.2.0
six==1.10.0
whitenoise==3.3.0
```

Also, when I run the app locally with `gunicorn remberit.wsgi` or `python manage.py runserver` it works fine, it only doesn't work when I use heroku.

Please tell me if you need anymore information.

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem. Please let me know if you've found the solution.

Answer (score 10):

Other solution that may solve your issue: Comment out or remover the GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage from whitenoise. For some reason this is not working well.

```
# STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

Found this solution on [Why would django fail with server 500 only when Debug=False AND db is set to production database on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28354179/why-would-django-fail-with-server-500-only-when-debug-false-and-db-is-set-to-pro/28385055#28385055)

Answer (score 8):

As [mustapha-belkacim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10992166/mustapha-belkacim) said, you need to migrate your apps:

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Do we have to do this even when we dont use database

Comment: @Arjun
If you have admin page or superuser, you need a database.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem when I first deployed my app to heroku, in my case it was the database that needs migrations. So I had to run this commande:

```
heroku run -a your-app-name python manage.py migrate
```

take a look at this tutorial https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#provision-a-database

Comment: This works but In my case I needed to first revert the migrations and the apply them again. That is: ```heroku run -a app-name python manage.py migrate zero``` and then the command in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Please provide (or check) your TEMPLATES variable from settings. Make sure the 'DIRS' value points to the right template folder where index.html (or base template) is.

I faced a similar error and this was the problem in my case.

As commented in other question ([Django app deployed to Heroku producing Server error 500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40854969/django-app-deployed-to-heroku-producing-server-error-500)), I realized this after turning DEBUG to True in production for a brief moment to find better help on the issue. Then, back to False of course.

Does your /admin works? If so, this answer might help you. If not, there is a number of things that can go wrong, maybe others can help? (eg: Why is psycopg2 not outputted with pip freeze if you have it in requirements.txt? Is it installed? Are you working with postgreSQL on both local and production environments?)

Comment: Good call. I turned DEBUG to True for a moment and saw the issue immediately.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same problem so the best and quickest solution is to remove this line:

`STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'`

and add this:

`STATICFILES_STORAGE =  'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'`

Answer (score 1):

A 500 error could be a lot of possible things. Set DEBUG=True temporarily to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you aren't linking any non existing external file, like in my case I had few css files linked with my html but the actual files were deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem but when I set **Debug** option in the **settings.py** to **false**, the site run as expected.